# Highchart group by month from corresponding column data

Tags: php, codeigniter, highcharts

I have a problem to group this data by month on the highchart categories.
[image]
Here's my controller code for the series data:

```
public function ajax_chart_data()
{
    $data = $this->lap_model->get_data();

    if (empty($data)){
        return json_encode('Tidak ada data');
    }else {
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $series_data[] = array(
                'name' => $row->Nama_Negara,
                'data' => [$row->Amount],
                'month' => $row->Month
                );
        }
        return json_encode($series_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }

}
```

And here's my view code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var base_url = "<?php base_url(); ?>";
var rpt1;
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#rpt1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Registration Data'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Reg. Amount'
            }
        },
        series: <?php echo $series_data ?>
    });
});
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="rpt1" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the current result of my highchart: 
[image]
I was expecting to group the data by monthly based as the data shown above.

Here's the data that returned by the ajax function if needed:

```
[{"name":"Brunei Darussalam","data":[5],"month":5},{"name":"Korea","data":[2],"month":4},{"name":"Korea","data":[3],"month":5},{"name":"Malaysia","data":[1],"month":4},{"name":"Malaysia","data":[6],"month":5},{"name":"Saudi Arabia","data":[2],"month":3},{"name":"Saudi Arabia","data":[1],"month":4},{"name":"Saudi Arabia","data":[8],"month":5},{"name":"Singapore","data":[1],"month":3},{"name":"Singapore","data":[6],"month":5},{"name":"Taiwan","data":[2],"month":3},{"name":"Taiwan","data":[1],"month":4},{"name":"Taiwan","data":[3],"month":5}]
```

I hope you guys understand what i mean and what im expecting, sorry for the trouble and many thanks in advance.

#Update:
Here's my code running on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HealMee/j32440f8/

Comment: You need to do something like `'data' => [$row->Bulan => $row->Jumlah]`, but then you also need to find a way of grouping together your name-column so you don't get multiple series for the same name.

Comment: @HalvorStrand why do i need to compare the month and the sum from each amount?

Comment: @HalvorStrand the multiple name means, say on april there're 3 registration for Malaysia, and march there're 6 registration for Malaysia. The $row->Jumlah is sum for each month of country. The $row->Bulan is the month number (1 is January,  etc). I have edited my question, sorry I didn't edited out before

Comment: Well from my understanding you want month as x-value, yes? But I think I made a bit of a mistake. Maybe more like `'data' => [['x' => $row->Month, 'y' => $row->Amount]]`, so the month becomes the x-value and the amount the y-value in your data. But still, each series only has 1 data point.

Comment: @HalvorStrand yes that's correct, i want the column month from selected data become x categories, i dont know the highchart function to pass the y data to the x.

Answer (score 1):

What your maen is
Month Maret
- Saudi Arab 2
- Taiwan 2
- Singapore 1
Month April
- Malaysia 1
- Saudi arab 1
- Korea 2
- Taiwan 1

Comment: This is what im expecting for, http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/